# Facebook SDK 3.23.0 with Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

First of all, when I try to add it with "import module" and then "add dependency" I get the error:

> Error:(19, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook'.

So I went ahead and created a gradle.properties file in the facebook module folder, then it gives me this error:

> Error:(111, 0) Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called.

For this I couldn't even find a similar problem on the web. Afterwards I tried to import it with maven. I followed the instructions on https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/ my build.gradle file:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.8.2.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
}
```

And the error I got is:

> Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk3211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJava
>   :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:dexDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lbolts/AggregateException;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 4.234 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

From what I saw in other similar questions, I thought maybe both facebook and parse are trying to compile `bolts-android-1.1.4.jar` and I commented it out but nothing changed.

I am working on this 8 hours straight now, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot call getBootClasspath() before setTargetInfo() is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689020/cannot-call-getbootclasspath-before-settargetinfo-is-called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the maven way, your app's `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    //    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.4.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.2.jar')
    //    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.8.2.jar')
}
```

And then in the terminal window go to your project's directory and type:

```
gradlew.bat clean
```

Reboot the Android Studio and you should good to go.

Comment: ./gradlew clean
was the solution in my case

Comment: this bug is already fixed. just change gradle version to 1.1.2 http://stackoverflow.com/a/28760740/2711056

Comment: @Krzysztof actually it was gradlew.bat clean in my case, I edited my answer.

Comment: `gradlew.bat clean` (once in project directory) does not work on a Mac.

Comment: Hey Noni, I don't have my mac with me right now so I couldn't take a look. However .bat is a Windows extension so there might be some gradlew.sh or something maybe?

Answer (score 8):

This is a [**known issue**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152811) , which [**is fixed**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) by updating gradle to :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
    }
```

credit to [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760740/878126).

Comment: Thanks for noting the duplicate - I've cast a close vote on the question.

Comment: I tried this, and solved the issue..but now I am getting Gradle dsl method not found. classpath(). Actually I updated the build.gradle dependecies of facebook..is that right?..

Comment: @sarath I don't know. There are tons of issues with Facebook SDK, and new ones appear all the time.

Comment: @sarath Even the FB rules change all the time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar issue and I thought it was Facebook since it happened around the time I added their newest sdk to my dependencies in `gradle.build` but it was just plain oversight on my part.  I had conflicting versions of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2` and `1.1.1` inside two different `gradle.build` files.

app/gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'
    ...
}
```

top-level gradle.build

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
```

I commented out the line in my project's `gradle.build` file, ran `gradlew clean` from the command line, restarted Android Studio and then order was restored in the universe.

Comment: top-level gradle.build -- that part saved my life literally

Answer (score 0):

you can Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28697252/2657401

This solve my problem for Facebook in Android Studio 1.1.0